# Handling Firebase Transactions Offline in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am developing an iOS app for accountancy. I am using Firebase for the backend. My app has offline capabilities.

In firebase documentation, it is clearly mentioned that "Transactions are not persisted across app restarts, make sure your app remembers them manually and executes them again after an app restart".

So my question is, How we can manage transaction manually when offline?

Comment: I think transactions are usually online! It can't be offline.

Comment: @AnuragSharma Exactly. But our use case is such that majority of transactions would take place when offline.

Comment: Firebase is really geared toward being an online database with offline persistence in case of interruption - it's really not designed to be used offline a majority of the time. If you need that, perhaps Firebase is not the right (or complete) solution.